# Flex - DataGrid Edit - a bug, or proper way to allow editing in a data grid?

Tags: apache-flex, events, datagrid, flash-builder

When I edit the last row of a grid, my itemEditEnd event method is called, but the data is not updated in my ArrayCollection to reflect the change made.  All the other columns work, just the last column seems to have a problem.   I am not sure if this is a bug, or I need to do something different?    (Flash Builder 4.5 / Flex 4.5.1)

I have a simple editable DataGrid with an ArrayCollection as it's data provider.   It populates and I can edit.   I am catching the [itemEditEnd](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/DataGrid.html#event%3aitemEditEnd) event and getting the row from my array collection to pass back to the server:

```
public var _recs:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection;

<mx:DataGrid id="recsDG" dataProvider="{_recs}" 
                 editable="true" itemEditEnd="recsDG_itemEditEndHandler(event)">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="id" dataField="id" editable="false"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="type" dataField="type"/>
... more columns ...
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>



protected function recsDG_itemEditEndHandler(event:DataGridEvent):void
        {
                    // THIS IS MY ARRAY COLLECTION/ROW(?):  _recs[event.rowIndex]
           }
```

If I click in to the last column a second time and change it again, I can see that the value in the array collection is now changed to the change I just made before.  For example, when debugger tracing, say my original value is "AAA", I change it to "BBB" and press tab, in the debugger in itemEditEnd, it shows "AAA" (only for this last column).   I then change the value to "CCC" and tab and in the debugger I see "BBB"!

I have also tried the  'event.currentTarget.itemEditorInstance.data'  property, and it also is not updated with the new value typed.

As a temporary work-around, I added an editable column at the end of my grid, no column title, 1 pixel wide.  That seems to work, when I tab out, now that it's no longer the last column, it seems to work.   Kind of a kluge though.

OH, I just noticed, when I click out, none of them are updating, it's only when I tab!   So that's another problem??

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your data provider is marked as [Bindable].  Also, try `_recs.refresh()` in your itemEditEnd handler method.  I set up the code below in a simple project and it seems to work fine (all the cells update the array collection immediately after pressing tab).  Also, I'm using the Flex 4.5.1 SDK.  If this does not solve your problem, can you post the full code you are using, or provide a sample app that reproduces the problem?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
</fx:Declarations>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.events.DataGridEvent;

        [Bindable]
        public var _data:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
            {id:1,name:'Ted',pos:'Mgr'},
            {id:2,name:'Bob',pos:'Mgr'},
            {id:3,name:'Jeb',pos:'Mgr'}
        ]);

        protected function dg_itemEditEndHandler(event:DataGridEvent):void
        {
            _data.refresh();
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:Panel title="Halo DataGrid Control Example"
         width="75%" height="75%" 
         horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0">
    <s:VGroup left="10" right="10" top="10" bottom="10">
        <s:Label width="100%" color="blue"
                 text="Select a row in the DataGrid control."/>

        <mx:DataGrid id="dg" width="100%" height="100%" rowCount="5" dataProvider="{_data}" editable="true" itemEditEnd="dg_itemEditEndHandler(event)">
            <mx:columns>
                <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="id" headerText="ID"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="name" headerText="NAME"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="pos" headerText="POSITION"/>
            </mx:columns>
        </mx:DataGrid>

        <mx:DataGrid id="dg2" width="100%" height="100%" rowCount="5" dataProvider="{_data}" editable="false" >
            <mx:columns>
                <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="id" headerText="ID"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="name" headerText="NAME"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="pos" headerText="POSITION"/>
            </mx:columns>
        </mx:DataGrid>
    </s:VGroup>
</s:Panel>
```